# Live google analytic chart

Tags: php, html, google-analytics, content-management-system

Hi can anyone point me in the right direction to get live google analytics to display in a line chart. I have a custom dashboard that I developed for all my custom CMS apps. So now I would like to add this feature to the dashboard.

I have googled quite a lot but can't find a solution.

Comment: Did you try the [Analytics APIs](https://developers.google.com/analytics)?

Comment: @Berriel I did check it out but I am a novice okay maybe a little better in Web Development but I can't make sense of it..0.o

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [Google Analytics Embed API](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/):

> The Google Analytics Embed API is a JavaScript library that allows you
>   to easily create and embed a dashboard on a third-party website in a
>   matter of minutes. It gives you a set of pluggable components that can
>   work together to build complex tools, making it both simple and
>   powerful at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to try the [Google Analytics Spreadsheet Add-On](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/google-analytics-spreadsheet-add-on?hl=en).  This lets you pull your analytics data into a spreadsheet which you can visualise in a number of ways.  If you then 'publish' this data it should then be easy to embed any charts you create into your CMS app.